# Is it feasible to build huge website using ajax jquery sqlserver?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I am developing a huge almost millions of users and very complex logic , secure and optimize web application.
but i am thinking to use client side archeticture with asp.net like gmail is using.
Any link , reference will be appriciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: let everyone know how to develop millions of users. Everyone can use some users I guess :)

Comment: asp.net is automatically generating webresources.xsd and some other files .. which can slow down my web site performence ... so i wanna get ride of these. how can i .

Comment: They are definitely doing things on the server.  What do you mean by "without any server side technology?"

Comment: good question. when i use asp.net updatepanel etc. then its automatically generate some sort of javascript file... so that may down my web site performence..

Comment: can you guide me which technology google or yahoo or msn use, there website is running very fast and having billions of records.

Comment: That is because they are caching many things.  Perhaps you should looking into caching.

Comment: yes, but  i am using akamai for caching the content.. and asp.net caching for data caching?

Comment: Your question is too vague, and it's uncertain if you even know what you're talking about.  You will need to think about what it is, exactly, that you want to know.  Do not be general.  Ask specific questions.

Comment: i can solve specific question using google. but wanna ask general and abastract knowldege from you expert people.

Comment: @Mystere-Man did you read the comments and answers before closing and vote down the question? kindly if you are moderator than read the questions and comments and then close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The client is never secure. You can't (shouldn't) trust the client to do the business logic.

On the other hand, Javascript can be used as the server-side language (similar in concept to Python, Rub, and PHP, among others).

Comment: I don't see why I should explain the basics of CLIENT-SERVER architecture to someone that is about to write "a huge almost millions of users and very complex logic , secure and optimize web application".

Comment: @Christian-Sciberras, its ok i know all that .. but at least you have to put your choice. you may know better than me.

Comment: i have asp.net than why use server side javascript

Comment: @Abdul Wakeel - I'm not saying you should use server-side javascript, I'm just saying you must use a server-side *something*.

Comment: @Christian-Sciberras your statment "Javascript can be used as the server-side language"

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether you can build an application with large amounts of client side Javascript, then, as you stated, the answer is yes.  In fact, Javascript has also become popular for server side development with technologies such as [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: but you know i want to hide complexity and logic, and most defiantly the db. and other stuff. but with javascript once user request the page all the javascript file is downloaded on the client pc. so security issue.

Comment: If you mean you want to hide these things from the user, server side javascript would accomplish this.

Comment: how, but again it will running slow. i have to tell you a story if you do not mind. recently i have developed an iphone web app using json jquery and asp.net webservices. nothing else.. no asp.net control just html pages... but that web apps is relatively small. and i packed all the javascript and json ... but the website which i am developig now. is very large and complex.so what technology you prefer

Comment: @Oren - I don't understand how you answer "yes you can use client-side javascript" and then in a latter comment say "you can use server-side javascript/node.js".

Comment: @Abdul Wakeel - You said one thing that's most important in this debate, databases. You would be a complete fool if you allowed your users to query the database directly in order to do the solution completely using client-side logic.

Comment: its not answer i just vote for feedback.

Comment: @Christian - The OP's question was (and still remains somewhat) ambiguous. I was merely stating that he can use Javascript in any manner he pleases.

Comment: @Christain-sciberras, exactly that is why i am asking from you expert.

Comment: @Oren - Using javascript as he wants is clearly false.

Comment: @Christian - What do you mean by false?  It is possible.  As you noted below, the OP needs to understand the concept that Javascript is in userland and can be fiddled with and that he will need to use some sort of server side language. That is the entire value of the question, as I see it.

Comment: yes exactly i am using now asp.net updatepanel and some sort of json but its running slow, and asp.net updatepanel generating some sort of javascript file like webresources.xsd.. now i am chaning the technology to pure javacript and html, json but i am afriad of the javascript injection and client side download.

Comment: @Oren - His notion of javascript seems to be client-side javascript, as he clearly said above. I'm afraid relying on client-side javascript alone is a huge no-no.

Comment: @Christian - I completely agree with you.

Comment: so now you both recognize what i am looking for? can you explain your answer little bit more.